# Can't render html page on the templates folder in the django project?

Tags: python, django

[Code of the views file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyOnI.png)

Template doesn't exist error is revoking. Firstly django-project is reading html file as django template file but I added "emmet.includeLanguages": {"django-html": "html"}, to settings.json but it doesn't help

Comment: Write your code instead of uploading image. See [How to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create or edit your template name to *index.htm*, then try:

```
def home(request) :
   .... code here.... 
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Let me know if you get an error.